# Unix Domain Sockets instead of host/port for TCP-type server

Tags: tcp, ipc, unix-socket

This is for all Node.js versions 6+

Say I have currently have a TCP server with multiple clients:

```
const server = net.createServer(s => {

});

server.listen(6000);
```

and I connect to it with clients:

```
const s1  = net.createConnection({port:6000});
const s2  = net.createConnection({port:6000});
const s3  = net.createConnection({port:6000});
```

TCP can sometimes be a bit slow on a local machine. I hear that there might be a way to substitute a host/port combination with Unix Domain Sockets, but maintain the TCP server style interface. Is this possible and how?

The Node.js docs mention you can create a server that listens on a path:
https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_path_backlog_callback

but it doesn't specify what kind of file that needs to be and how to create that file.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out on MacOS/Linux this is easy. You don't need to create the file. You need to make sure the file does not exist, and then point the Node.js core libraries to an empty path.

For the server:

```
const udsPath = path.resolve('some-path.sock');

const wss = net.createServer(s => {

});

wss.listen(udsPath, () => {


});
```

For the clients:

```
const udsPath = path.resolve('some-path.sock'); // same file path as above

const ws = net.createConnection(udsPath, () => {
});
```